# adding LayerControl and map visual options in folium

Tags: python, pandas, graph, maps, folium

I am trying to add two layers, one for map view options, and the other for filtering data. when I use map view options, it works, when I apply the filter option, it shows options, but on checking and unchecking boxes, the map does not update. when I try both options simultaneously, only the last view option applies on the map and the filter disappears. My code is:

```
    import folium
import pandas as pd

data = [
        ['A', 24.8483945, 66.99847413, 'ASDF'],
        ['A', 24.84493504, 66.99694272, 'BSDF'],
        ['B', 24.84472664, 66.99510545, 'CSDF'],
        ['B', 24.84866494, 67.00017693, 'ASDF'],
        ['C', 24.84927827, 67.0010406, 'BSDF'],
        ['C', 24.84948272, 67.00271967, 'CSDF']
      ]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Insti', 'Lat', 'Long', 'IslCon'])
  
a_list = df[['Lat','Long', 'IslCon']].values.tolist()

# create empty map zoomed in on Pakistan
map = folium.Map(location = [24.84472664,66.99510545], overlay=True, control=False ,zoom_start=15)

fg = folium.FeatureGroup(name='Locations')
#fg = folium.FeatureGroup()


for i in a_list:
    fg.add_child(folium.Marker(location=[i[0] , i[1]], tooltip=i[2], icon=folium.Icon(color='green',icon="bank", prefix='fa')))
map.add_child(fg)

#m_option = ['Stamen Terrain', 'Stamen Toner' ]
#for m in m_option:
#    folium.TileLayer().add_child(m_option[m])

folium.TileLayer('Stamen Terrain').add_to(map)
folium.TileLayer('Stamen Toner').add_to(map)    
folium.LayerControl().add_to(map)

#storing unique institutes in features dictionary
features = {}
for row in pd.unique(df["Insti"]):
    features[row] = folium.FeatureGroup(name=row)
    
for row in pd.unique(df["Insti"]):
    features[row].add_to(map)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(map)
#map

map
```